# How to disable Spring Security popup when sending wrong credentials

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-security, axios, authorization

I am implementing Spring Security in my full stack web application but there is a problem I'm running into.

I am using a React front-end with a custom login form and it works just fine when I fill in correct credentials. But when I fill in wrong credentials, it gives me a window alert from by back-end with once again the login form. I understand why this is happening, because it is also happening when I try to visit my back-end directly. But there must be a way to disable this right? See the screenshot below:

[image: When I use credentials that are not known to my system, I get a popup straight from the back-end]

My Spring Security configuration:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
                csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic();
    }
```

My axios request in React:

```
if(document.getElementById("username").value !== "" && document.getElementById("password").value !== "") {
        axios.get(baseUrl + "users/name/" + document.getElementById("username").value , {
            withCredentials : true,
            headers : {
                authorization : 'Basic ' + window.btoa(document.getElementById("username").value + ':' + document.getElementById("password").value)
            }}).then(response => {
                localStorage.setItem('creds', window.btoa(document.getElementById("username") + ":" + document.getElementById("password")));
                console.log("Credentials stored in local storage.");
                console.log(response.data);
                window.location.replace("/");
                    }
                ).catch((e) => {
                    window.alert("Incorrect username or password. Please try again!");
            }
        )
    } else {
        window.alert("Please fill in username and password.")
    }
```

As you can see I'm also catching any error that can occur and sending an alert myself. I do get this custom alert, but I also still get the login popup. Any ideas?

Comment: That isn't a Spring Security popup, that is the default basic authentication popup from your browser.

Comment: @M.Deinum Oh ok good to know, do you know any way to disable this though?

Comment: No, that is a browser default, so basically I would say that you're client-side handling isn't fully correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot security shows Http-Basic-Auth popup after failed login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37763186/spring-boot-security-shows-http-basic-auth-popup-after-failed-login)